# Highcharts - Different display month

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm new in using highcharts and work by example.
I have issue when displaying some data in highcharts.

Here is my series data (var_dump)

```
'series_data' => string '[ 
{name:'Inmobi',data:[
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 01),311328],[Date.UTC(2013, 05, 02),363780],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 03),364062],[Date.UTC(2013, 05, 04),283128],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 05),322608]] },
{name:'Buzz City',data:[
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 01),363216],[Date.UTC(2013, 05, 02),404670],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 03),370783],[Date.UTC(2013, 05, 04),459942],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 05, 05),569499]] }]'
```

When it displayed in highcharts, the month shifting to June (it should be May).
https://www.dropbox.com/s/girftyfs8a71n9k/highcharts.jpg

I wonder what's the problem.

here is the highcharts renderer script

```
<script language="javascript">
var chart_type = 'column';
var series_data = <?=$series_data?>;

    var chart;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'site_statistics',
        type: chart_type
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Ad Spend',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date '
            },
        type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%e %b',
                week: '%e %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
        },
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Cost '
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b',this.x)  +': '+ accounting.formatMoney(this.y, "Rp", 0, ".", "") +'';
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: series_data
    });
```

I'd highly appreciated for any help.

regards

Comment: may be you need subtract the month by 1 coz JS array begin 0

Answer (score 1):

It is correct because in Highcharts name of months by default starts from 0 to 11.
from 0- January to 11- December.

[image]

So for the month of may you should write 4 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Date will accept the month value 0 - 11. 0 is the january and 11 is the December. So 6 referes to the June.

[Check the documentation of javascript date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)